# Overriding media queries without using an iFrame

Tags: media-queries

I have a special requirement:

I'd like to wrap a responsive website in a div that can change width and height. The end result is that I'd have a drop down where I'd change the width and height of this div, allowing the "site" contained in the div to render to the width and the heigh of the div.

- I cannot use iFrames
- Browser plugins that allow me to do this will not work (these will not necessarily be browser machines)

Basically, I'd like to "mock out" the browser's API for media queries.

Comment: So similar to the sites that allow you to test screen widths for responsive layouts but with/out iframes? I would think you could modify the way the IE responsive.js works to FORCE certain media queries. Essnetially it grabs the screen width and looks through the CSS for media queries and applies the styles manually. I would think you could use the same js and just enter your own screen width.